# Does browserSync clear laravel session when server disconnected from BrowserSync?

Tags: angularjs, session, laravel-5, browser-sync

I'm using laravel 5 with angularjs in my project. I added browserSync with gulp into it but I face a problem when I try to log in the system. The system won't redirect to homepage even if the user is already authenticated. It shows "`Disconnected from BrowserSync`" whenever redirection occurs. I think this is a browserSync issue where it clears auth session when it is disconnected. Can anyone tell me whether it's true that session will be cleared when browserSync is disconnected?